# Illogical damage count?

Tags: skullgirls

I had basic knowledge of versus fighting games, but never tried to play one seriously (first experience was with SF4 on Xbox 360 and pretty confusing). I loved Skullgirls's graphic style, so I decided to buy it with the recent Steam discount and I enjoy trying to chain combos in training mode (the lowest level AI still crushes me, though).

I spotted an odd thing while playing Ms. Fortune: a 9 hit combo damage total (as displayed in the training mode) is lower than a pretty similar 8 hit combo. The base combo is Standing Low Punch → Standing Low Kick → Standing Medium Kick (2 hits) → Crouched High Punch (Launcher) → Aerial Low Punch → Aerial Low Kick → Aerial High Kick.

I tried squeezing another Standing Low Punch at the start to do one more hit and potentially more damage, but the final result is 2844 for 8 hit combo and 2812 for 9 hit combo. Damages are adding consistently (8 hit total < 9 hit total) until the final Aerial High Kick.

Is it a feature? Or a glitch?

Subsidiary: is it worth adding an air dash cancel at the start of the aerial part of the combo to do one more Aerial Low Punch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a pretty standard mechanic in fighting games.

Each hit in a combo scales down the damage of all future hits in the combo. This mechanic is in place for a few reasons. Primarily, it dissuades the use of infinite combos (if they even can exist in the game), and keeping shorter, hard-hitting combos more lucrative allows your opponent to get back into the game faster and start playing again.

Therefore, throwing in an extra weak hit *early* in the combo is almost always a bad idea, because the extra damage you get from it isn't going to overcome the lost damage on later hits from the scaling down.

A natural evolution in gameplay from this mechanic is what's called a "reset". A reset is where you intentionally end your combo, potentially earlier than you might have normally, and use a mixup to try to trick your opponent into letting you start a new combo. This resets the scaling and you will hit for full damage again on the first hit, subject to scaling again. A character who makes frequent use of mixup resets is known as a "vortex" character.

Comment: This mechanic is commonly called "proration". In addition to dissuading infinite combos, it allows hefty moves to be thrown in the end of combos without being overwhelmingly unbalancing - comboing into a super would make it generally easier to land that super, so the damage is reduced to accommodate that.

Comment: http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Skullgirls/Game_Elements/Life_and_Damage#Damage_Scaling explains the damage scaling system in SG and also links directly to other complex topics like their infinity breaker rules.